# Sofware center hanging..

Tags: software-center, launcher, skype

Newly installed 16.04 on new dell laptop.

Tried using software centre in order to download skype. Software centre failed to launch, hanging for a while. Launcher info corrupt?

Not sure in what sequence:

- launched as software-center from command line (but did not find skype)
- re-installed and rebooted
- did not launch from launcher, so removed entry from launcher
- re-installed again, still not finding either skype or opencpn (apps that I use)

So much old info around very confused as to current status..

Answer (score 0):

The repository may have been corrupted. You can use the following command to clean out your apt list:

```
sudo rm -r /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

Then update with

```
sudo apt update
```

or

```
sudo apt-get update
```

If you still can't find the Skype package you can [download it](https://www.skype.com/en/get-skype/) and install it with:

```
sudo dpkg -i SKYPE_PACKAGE.deb
```

Comment: If you need to remove the package you can use     sudo dpkg -r SKYPE_PACKAGE.deb

Comment: Thanks, guys... still in a hole. Refreshing the list worked, but still no skype, and downloading it did not work either. I am running software-center from the command line, but picking up that that has now been superceded by gnome-software? More research needed.

Comment: gnome-software from terminal just hangs. Have removed software-center in case of conflict (which appeared to be ok). Gnome software is at 3.20.5 and ubuntu is 0.16.04.10

Comment: aptitude shows 32 updates available, but can't fathom how to use the beast..

Comment: Try using sudo apt-get upgrade